# Change fontsize in beamer theme bars

Tags: beamer, fontsize

I am creating a beamer presentation and using `10pt` fontsize. At that fontsize, the subsection titles that appear in the `smoothbars` are small. Is there a way to make it larger?

My simple code is

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}

\begin{document}
 \section{Section}
 \subsection{Subsection}
 \begin{frame}
  The first frame
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

My output is

[image]

What I want to achieve is enlarge the fontsize and/or the subsection smooth bar. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility: First change the beamerfont `headline` and then reset the beamerfont `section in head/foot` to `\tiny`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\setbeamerfont{headline}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\tiny}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
 \section{Section}
 \subsection{Subsection}
 \begin{frame}
  The first frame
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The thing is that I want only the `subsection` font to change and not the `section` i.e. the bottom bar in the headline.

Comment: @Thanos See my edited answer.